# Is it possible to install gopkg.in packages in Docker?

Tags: oracle, docker, go

I am trying to run golang application which use [goracle](https://github.com/go-goracle/goracle) library with such Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.12

RUN go get github.com/gorilla/mux && \
  go get github.com/gorilla/handlers && \
  go get github.com/lib/pq && \
  go get github.com/joho/godotenv && \
  go get github.com/jinzhu/gorm && \
  go get gopkg.in/goracle.v2

ADD ./ /go/src/application

WORKDIR /go/src/application

RUN go build -o /bin application

ENV PORT=8000

CMD ["/bin"]
```

Unfortunatly it raise error when I try to create image:

```
package gopkg.in/goracle.v2: unrecognized import path "gopkg.in/goracle.v2" (https fetch: Get https://gopkg.in/goracle.v2?go-get=1: proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake)
The command '/bin/sh -c go get github.com/gorilla/mux &&   go get github.com/gorilla/handlers &&   go get github.com/lib/pq &&   go get github.com/joho/godotenv &&   go get github.com/jinzhu/gorm &&   go get gopkg.in/goracle.v2' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Why I can't install goracle library in Docker? How to fix this problem?

Comment: Try the `-insecure` flag for that import. [more info](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies).

Comment: Also read up on [go build](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies), specifically the section on the `-o` flag. I believe you're using it wrong.

Comment: @mkopriva you mean use `go get -insecure gopkg.in/goracle.v2`? I tried it. Unfortunatly the result was the same. What exatly in `go build` command is wrong for your opinion?

Comment: Why are you using `/bin` as the output file? I've commented on your previous question that that can't possibly be a good choice. Just look at the error output, the docker container is using `/bin/sh` to run the commands in the dockerfile. If you overwrite that folder with your binary, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I shall take full account of your last comment. I will change it to `RUN go build -o "app"`. It steal unclear to me with `gopkg.in`. Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: When you use the `-insecure` flag, are you getting the same exact error? Is it still saying `... proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I add `-insecure` flag as you adviced. Finally I used this: `go get -insecure gopkg.in/goracle.v2`. The error message was the same.

Comment: If `-insecure` doesn't work then I don't know how else to fix that. However you could work around the issue by vendoring your dependencies. There are multiple 3rd party solutions for how to do this, and there's also Go's own module system that should work.

Comment: Do you know any other packages which I can use to connect Golang application to Oracle database?

Comment: I'm afraid not, I've never used oracle.

Comment: For generic troubleshooting with building docker images, I like to use commands like `docker run --rm -it golang:1.12 /bin/sh`. Unfortunately when I do that and immediately `go get -v gopkg.in/goracle.v2`, I don't observe any errors. You could try running the same commands on your own machine, though, in case that yields some more information (I don't want to assume it's an obscure DNS thing, but it might be an obscure DNS thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the `CentOS` server where was located `Docker` has proxy. For thats why I couldn't download the `gopkg.in/goracle.v2` package.

**SOLUTION**:

1) Create `vender` folder inside your project.

2) Remove source code of `gopkg.in/goracle.v2` package which you has in `go/src` folder to `vender` folder.

3) Run you Dockerfile.

In my case this instruction removed problem with importing of `gopkg.in/goracle.v2` 
 package.

I hope this post will helpful for somebody!